# What is the probability of drawing all 4 queens after drawing the first king and before drawing the third king in a deck of cards?

Tags: probability

> In a deck of cards there are $4$ different suits, and $13$ cards of each suit (1-10, Queen, King and Jack). What is the probability of drawing all 4 queens after drawing the first king and before drawing the third king?

I thought about the whole deck first and also tried thinking of the 8 cards and placing each one at a time but don't get the right answer of $1/14$.

I have seen a solution that places the king in the first, seventh and eighth places and doesn't take into account the placing of the queens.
Why is this possible?

I would appreciate any insights in this. TIA

One of the ways I tried:

A - getting $4$ queens after first king and before third king

B -  getting first king in place $k $

\begin{align*}
P(A \mid B_k) & = \left(\dfrac{44}{48}\right)^{k-1}\\
P(B_k) & = \left(\dfrac{48}{52}\right)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{52}\\
P(A) & = \sum P(A \mid B_k)P(B_k)
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you please show your work so we can spot your mistake?

Comment: I don't see how just placing the kings in positions 1,7, and 8 can be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering only the Kings and Queens should give you the right answer. [ This is because we are looking for  *patterns* of Kings and Queens, where the other cards are interspersed does not matter.]

One such pattern that fulfills the criteria is as below:

$\boxed{K}\boxed{KQQQQ}\boxed{KK}$

But in the middle box, the $K$ could be in any of $5$ places, and without any constraints, the Kings and Queens could be placed in $\large{\binom84} = 70$ ways,

hence $Pr = \dfrac{5}{70} = \dfrac 1{14}$

Comment: I don't understand why we can look at a particular arrangement. That is what I referred to as "placing the kings in positions 1,7, and 8". If we thought of it as tossing two dices, and of the probability of getting a sum of 11 after getting 12, could we think about only two tossings as well?

Comment: If each toss of two dice is considered  one experiment, P(sum 11) = 2/36,  P(sum 12) = 1/36, but we can ignore others, to compare the two  events to get P(sum 11)= 2/3 and P(sum 12) = 1/3.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to be of help :)